# Whats wrong with this less-than date query?

Tags: sql, sqlite

```
sqlite> SELECT * FROM RawResponseTimes WHERE CreationTime <= 2011-06-14 17:17:23;
Error: near ":17": syntax error
```

Everything appears to be fine but it isn't happy with the hour 17, what gives?

Using SQLite.

Comment: The reason it's throwing up on `17`, is because it believes that you are attempting to subtract `2011 - 06 - 14`. It then gets to 17 and has no idea what you're attempting to do.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Keep data value in single quotes...

`sqlite> SELECT * FROM RawResponseTimes WHERE CreationTime <= '2011-06-14 17:17:23';`

Answer (score 32):

Looks like you are missing `'`s from your date.

`SELECT * FROM RawResponseTimes WHERE CreationTime <= '2011-06-14 17:17:23';`

Comment: Thanks guy! Stupid mistake but a bit too trivial to search for in Google easily. I'd vote up if I could!

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM RawResponseTimes WHERE CreationTime <= CONVERT(DATETIME, '2011-06-14 17:17:23');
```